# Issue with namespace import in BPEL with WSO2 BPS

Tags: wso2, bpel

I´m using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0.

I develop a simple bpel process using this tutorial:
http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/10/develop-ws-bpel-process-using-wso2.html

with an issue because two ws import with the same namespace
http://ws.apache.org/axis2

So I decided to implement my own web services with different namespaces.
Now I have this issue with the Adder and Square services:

```
The file cannot be imported because the namespace 'http://square.org.jorgesoftdevelop' does not match the target
namespace 'http://ws.apache.org/axis2' of the imported
document.       EquationBPELProccesArtifacts.wsdl

The file cannot be imported because the namespace
'http://adder.org.jorgesoftdevelop' does not match the target
namespace 'http://ws.apache.org/axis2' of the imported
document.       EquationBPELProccesArtifacts.wsdl
```

My imports look like:

```
<import location="http://localhost:9765/services/AdderService?wsdl" namespace="http://adder.org.jorgesoftdevelop"/>
<import location="http://localhost:9765/services/MultiplyService?wsdl" namespace="http://multiply.org.jorgesoftdevelop"/>
<import location="http://localhost:9765/services/SubtractService?wsdl" namespace="http://org.jorgesoftdevelop"/>
<import location="http://localhost:9765/services/SquareService?wsdl" namespace="http://square.org.jorgesoftdevelop"/>
```

And the namespaces are OK.
I don´t use the http://ws.apache.org/axis2 namespace in any ws.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Import any WSDL inside the project and put at the same level of the BPEL´s WSDL.
2. Use different namespace for every wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing a wsdl with the target namespace "http://ws.apache.org/axis2" and assigning a new namespace for two wsdl files. These two should be same. 
Change the target namespace of each wsdl to the corresponding namespace you put in  element.Put those wsdl files in same folder where Bpel file is and change location attribute to wsdl filename.